# Load dynamic AngularJS in a legacy html with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to load dynamic content with AngularJS but does not work.

I have a system with legacy pages with dynamic load using JQuery but now I am developing some new features using AngularJS and have same trouble in dynamic load.

The follow code show exact my problem (https://jsfiddle.net/alvarof/w7ynuro8/):

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrender/0.9.75/jsrender.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="static">
    <div ng-controller="StaticCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Static Table</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td>{[{item}]}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="!items.length">
                <td>No items!</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="dynamic">
</div>

<button onclick="loadDynamicContent()">Load dynamic content</button>
</body>


<script id="dynamic_tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
<div ng-controller="DynamicCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Dynamic Table</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>{[{item}]}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="!items.length">
            <td>No items!</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</script>

<script>
    var loadDynamicContent = function () {
        $("#dynamic").html($("#dynamic_tmpl").render());
        //FORCE RECOMPILE Angular????
    }

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
    });

    myApp.controller('StaticCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = ['StaticCtrl: element 1', 'StaticCtrl: element 2', 'StaticCtrl: element 3', 'StaticCtrl: element 4'];
    });

    myApp.controller('DynamicCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = ['DynamicCtrl: element 1', 'DynamicCtrl: element 2', 'DynamicCtrl: element 3', 'DynamicCtrl: element 4'];
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Anyone had the same problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Templates that have AngularJS directives and interpolation need to be compiled with the `$compile` service.

Comment: Ok, but for use $compile I need to call inside a controller and it was executed on load html at first time. When I push the button "Load dynamic content" the AngularJS was running and all controllers executed. Is it possible to call the $compile with other way? Thanks

Comment: The AngularJS directive for dynamically loading templates is `ng-include`. For more information, see [AngularJS ng-include Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).

Comment: Yes is the best approach but in my case I have a legacy system and I'd like to make small changes. Thanks for your sharing informations!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your expression ***{[{item}]}*** is not correct check the documentation for angularjs expressions then why did you use **ng-template** refer template matching in angularjs

Comment: I change the default symbols. myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
    });